# django templates in model logic

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I wish to generate automated messages that are associated with a finite (>20, < 100) number of types:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    MSG_CHOICES = (
        ('MEETING', 'Meeting Reminder'),
        ('STATUS', 'Status Change Reminder'),
        ...
        )
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    msg_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MSG_CHOICES)
```

The actual message of each will depend on the type and arguments I must feed it at some point. For example, a 'MEETING' message will basically be:

```
"Hi, you have a meeting at %s with %s." % (time, person_to_meet)
```

while a 'STATUS' message will be something like

```
"Hi, this is a reminder that you changed your %s status to %s." % (status_type, new_status)
```

Now, the complexity here is that we have to render the message differently for the different types. Here's my attempt at brainstorming some different approaches:

1. revamp the model to have a base message model and a derived one for each, with its own type of constructor, saving the "string templates" inside the constructors for each model. This fits the pattern of separating models with different logic (and I'd usually do this for a model of different "types"), but feels clunky because besides the logic of creating the messages, these guys are basically the same. The only difference in logic comes from creating the messages themselves, and it seems like a waste to split just because of it.
2. keep the model as is, create class methods in the code to make a factory for each type, saving the "string templates" inside the class (or even inside the database). This is the easiest, but it feels dirty.
3. this is the creative/crazy one (hence the title): keep the model as is, and save the string templates as actual template files. In the constructors, use the Django template library to render those files and return the strings. This seems good because it separates out hard-coded data from code-logic, but it feels wonky since I'm using templates at two different levels of the code (one for making models and one for the views). It "feels" wrong but I can't really pinpoint why.

So the main questions:

1. What is the best-practice for this situation? Is it one of these or is it some other approach?
2. is there a "model" example of this practice somewhere? I feel lots of systems generate automated alerts/messages, so if one has particularly good code I'd like to look at it.

Thanks!

-Yan

Comment: Looking your message samples seems that a post_save method may be a good point to raise it. What do you think?. My application also raise messages and also I don't know where is the best point to raise it, on view or on post_save. I follow your question.

Comment: well if the question is just do do it on view or on post_save, I feel post_save is strictly better than the view because this association of a human-readable message to the data used to generate the message is model-level logic and should not be view-dependent. What do you think?

Comment: I'm waiting for someone that answer your question. In my opinion: in first time I have wrote this rules in post_save, but was hard to check just for conditions that message should raise, then I move to views. At this time I'm moving back to post_save. I prefear allways write code and business rules on models.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you shouldn't be storing the message in the db at all.  You are storing the msg_type.  That should really be enough.  Your logic to display the information to the user (via the template) should handle this.  This would allow you to localize the message if you needed to at some point in the future based on the Accept-Language header.  In my experience, it's a bad idea to store user messages in the db.  And, at least to my way of thinking, it's not really true business logic.  It seems to belong in the UI layer.  Ok.  Just my opinion on it.  This question is pretty old.  I would be curious to read what you ultimately ended up doing here.